# How use session variable in sql using php

Tags: php, sql, session, variables

I have a problem with displaying files added by the logged user.
I do not know how to pass the variable correctly to the sql query.
Can anyone help me with this?

Currently, the code looks like this:

```
    <?php
include_once 'dbconnect.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>File Uploading With PHP and MySql</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
<label>File Uploading With PHP and MySql</label>
</div>
<div id="body">
 <table width="80%" border="1">
    <tr>
    <th colspan="4">your uploads...<label><a href="index.php">upload new files...</a></label></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>File Name</td>
    <td>File Type</td>
    <td>File Size(KB)</td>
    <td>View</td>
    </tr>
    <?php
 $sql="SELECT * FROM files";
 $result_set=mysql_query($sql);
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result_set))
 {
  ?>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['file'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['type'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['size'] ?></td>
        <td><a href="uploads/<?php echo $row['file'] ?>" target="_blank">view file</a></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
 }
 ?>
    </table>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to change this record :

`$sql="SELECT * FROM files";`

to

`$sql="SELECT file, type, size FROM files WHERE userId ='$_SESSION[userId]'";`

but I still do not get the correct result. Can anyone help?

Comment: mysql is deprecated, use mysqli instead.

Comment: can you specify what you mean?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the issue with that line is in how you are including the $_SESSION variable. You should have quotes around `userId` like `$_SESSION['userId']` or `{$_SESSION['userId']}`.

More importantly you should avoid entering variables directly into MySQL queries. I would recommend using [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead of MySQL, and look into prepared statements ([here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), for example).